# Get the value of input of type number with query without id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML table with spinners in every row. Here is the code for the spinner.

```
<INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1"  SIZE="6" id='spinner'>
```

Because all the ids are the same i don't want to use the ID to get it in jquery so i get it with the following code:

```
var count = $('#'+ids).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)');
```

If I do `alert(count.html())` then I get the code of the spinner. But how can I get the value of the spinner?. I tried `alert(count.val())` but it is empty. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by value...do you want text in td?

Comment: ids should be unique to a page

Comment: As you mention in your question `"all the ids are the same "` then serious problem in your markup. ID should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The code* of the spinner **isn't** the spinner. What you're getting is the content of the parent `td` of it. Why not:

```
var count = $('#'+ids).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1) input:first');
```

Then your `count.val()` will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
var td = $('#'+ids).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)'); 
var count = td.children("input");
var value = count.val();
```

should work.

1 get the TD

2 get the child of the TD (the input)

3 get the value of the input